# How do I make perfect sprite sheets?

Tags: animation, spritesheet

I made a .GIF using sprite sheet animation, but I do not think it is working properly, because it shivers at the base. I made it in Photoshop Max Power.

[image: My animation.]

How do I easily make perfect sprite sheets with images? I want to be able to add my images, resize them for my game and create a sprite sheet. Alternate software recommendation might be considered.

Comment: try https://www.gutils.com This is a web-based spritesheet creator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you cropped the images to the characters bounds for each frame. The images are being drawn from a fixed point in space and thus will appear to shift. An easy fix would be to have a fixed size for your image. This size should be big enough to fit the largest frame.

If this easy fix simply takes up too many texture space then you should manually fix each frame. Often you end up with some kind of atlas to lookup the frames within the sheet. Here you can make changes depending on the atlas format.